# I see my full site at another domain

Tags: domain-name-system, website, attacks

Today I found one of my website fully being displayed at another domain that is not mine.
Is this some kind of DNS hack or what is the purpose of these actions ? Because I seen this before, few years ago, all content from Adobe Exchange (user uploaded content) was being displayed at many other domains.

Should I be worried about anything ?

**Edit:** I pinged that domain and it shows same IP address as my own domain.
My site is a new/small social networking site with a bit under 3000 users.
I found this other domain while looking at traffic sources.

**Edit:** The other domain that shows my site is forum.[domain].com and their main domain shows illegal downloads, it also has 20 000 Alexa traffic rank.

Temporary I made a test in my php scripts and if http_host is different than my domain, then it exists, this seems to work, but I probably need to edit some DNS settings to stop it from serving my site to outside domains. **How do I do that ?**

**Edit:** Inside Plesk panel under `ip addresses` I removed the `default domain` for that IP and this caused that other site to show a default Plesk panel (same page that is shown if someone directly types my IP in browser.

Comment: Do you have shared hosting that might be misconfigured by your provider?

Comment: It is a dedicated hosting managed by me. I use Plesk panel that handles the DNS records, is there a speciffic DNS setting that I should look at? Something that allows *ANY* domain to associate to my IP ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/444217/126632

Comment: I have the same problem today. After checking the apache log I saw that somebody accessed my website with the wrong referer. After that, I can access my website with another DNS name!!

Comment: Same problem here! I tried everything suggested: still I am getting my website from another DNS name!

Answer (score 3):

First, check if it's actually your site or a copy. Do a `nslookup your_domain.com` and `nslookup the_other_domain.com` and see if the results are the same.

This is not a hack, at least not against you. More likely than not it's someone setting up for a phishing attack against your clients/customers/whatever. It's also possible that someone plans on using your design for their own site and just hasn't removed the content (what you can do varies depending on the country you reside in, and where the hosting server resides). In any case I wouldn't be too worried unless this website is related to financial information (in which case you should try to warn users that someone might be trying a phishing attack, and to check the URL anytime they use your site).

I am curious how you found another domain with your content. It's not something that I would likely run across if I were in your shoes.

Comment: I did a ping on that domain, as I expected, it show same IP as my site. My domain is a social networking site (I added this info on the question now). I located this issue by looking at traffic sources of my site.

Comment: @chris-s In my case, it was the referrer logs. Most of the places doing the content slurping weren't smart enough to even copy my images, they just left the links in and I saw a lot of non-local referrers all coming in from the same site.

Comment: @adrianTNT Well, this is just plain weird. Fortunately you can block the hostname on your server pretty easily if you want (or better, what I would do, redirect traffic from that domain to your domain).

Comment: @ChrisS I used to have my site show up if you entered server IP in browser, I think this alone exposed it to this issue. As soon as I removed a "default domain" from my IP, the other site shows a default server page. This seems to be it: http://serverfault.com/q/444217/126632