# Block Malicious Redirect

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, security

I have website domain hosted on GoDaddy and code deployed on AWS elastic beanstalk. I found some other IPs and APIs calls redirect to my website and none of the IPs and APIs used by me i.e. completely unknown. When I open the unknown API it opens my website home page, I think someone did redirection in their domain server host and redirects all calls to my website.

Example of current scenario: - mywebsite-- [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) domain in Godaddy, unknown API/IP -- 122.166.100.2/sdk. When I open 122.166.100.2/sdk this redirect to [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com).

How can I stop/prevent these kinds of scenario? Please help me with this.

Code written in python (django) and server is wsgi

Thanks

Comment: Is there actually something clearly malicious about this or is it just misguided/strange things that others are doing? 
You cannot really stop others from redirecting wherever they want, so the question leaves me wondering if what they are doing somehow causes some kind of actual problem for you. If not, it seems like it may be a waste of time and resources to do anything more than to shrug at random people on the internet doing things wrong.

Comment: Are you not even running a web server?! apache, nginx, etc?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes it is apache wsgi

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist yes it is causing the issue because in a particular time unknow hits increase the server resource uses and when I say malicious hits means 1000+ hits per second.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent Apache from answering requests for domains I don't host?](https://serverfault.com/questions/444217/how-do-i-prevent-apache-from-answering-requests-for-domains-i-dont-host)